# Google sheets compare values in 2 columns and email list when matching conditions

Tags: google-apps-script

Sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HhJZXDGr1KmAAiYBTIQG_omNT26ZYOFqbes2U7rif6I/edit?usp=sharing

I have an email alert setup which emails me a list of "Equip" from the "Maint. Schedule" tab when the value in Column "U" (engine oil due) reaches a value equal to or greater than 15 less of Column "S" (Current Hours) value.
My issue is, I receive as many emails as the amount of equipment meeting the email requirements. Some emails have a single piece of equipment included, some have all, and some have a varying amount of pieces included. I don't know enough to find the specific issue. Neither am I familiar with the way this site works so, noob alert.

This is my current code. I did copy/paste and modify from the internet somewhere, if this is your code, I don't remember where I got it to thank you!

```
function sendTableEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maint Sched."); // Get your table data
  var startRow = 4;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 22); // Fetch the range of cells A7:D
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Fetch values for each row in the Range.

      
  // Loop through the data to build your table
  var message = "<html><body><table style=\"text-align:center\"></tr><th>Vehicle</th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Due</th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Current</th></tr>";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var equip = rowData[1]
    var current = rowData[18];
    var due = rowData[20];
    if (due > 0) {
      if (current+15 >= due) {
      Logger.log(equip + " " + current + " " +due)
        var equip = rowData[1]
        var current = rowData[18];
        var due = rowData[20];
        message += "<tr><td>"+equip+"</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>"+due+"</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>"+current+"</td></tr>";
        message += "</table></body></html>";
        var subject = "Services Due";
        MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "*********", 
        subject: subject, 
        htmlBody: message
      } )
    }
  } ;
 };
}
```

I added Logger which shows correct info leaving me to believe the issue is somehow with the email function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each loop, you are adding stuff in `message` with operator `+=` and send email. So first email will contains only 1 element, last email will have all.

If you want to send only one mail at the end of the job :

```
  function sendTableEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maint Sched."); // Get your table data
  var startRow = 4;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 22); // Fetch the range of cells A7:D
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Fetch values for each row in the Range.

  // Loop through the data to build your table
  var message = "<html><body><table style=\"text-align:center\"></tr><th>Vehicle</th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Due</th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Current</th></tr>";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    // var equip = rowData[1]
    var current = rowData[18];
    var due = rowData[20];
    if (due > 0) {
      if (current+15 >= due) {
        Logger.log(equip + " " + current + " " +due)
        var equip = rowData[1]
        var current = rowData[18];
        var due = rowData[20];
        message += "<tr><td>"+equip+"</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>"+due+"</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>"+current+"</td></tr>";
      }
    }
  }
  var subject = "Services Due";
  message += "</table></body></html>";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "*********", 
    subject: subject, 
    htmlBody: message
  });
}
```

Or if you want to send email for every loop :

```
  var message; 
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    //re-init message at each loop
    message = "<html><body><table style=\"text-align:center\"></tr><th>Vehicle</th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Due</th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Current</th></tr>";

    var rowData = data[i];
    var equip = rowData[1]
    var current = rowData[18];
    var due = rowData[20];
    if (due > 0) {
      if (current+15 >= due) {
      Logger.log(equip + " " + current + " " +due)
        var equip = rowData[1]
        var current = rowData[18];
        var due = rowData[20];
        message += "<tr><td>"+equip+"</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>"+due+"</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>"+current+"</td></tr>";
        message += "</table></body></html>";
        var subject = "Services Due";
        MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "*********", 
        subject: subject, 
        htmlBody: message
      } )
    }
  } ;
```

Comment: Thanks! I want one email at the end of the job. I implemented (read copy/paste, minor edit) your top code block and now I get a blank email with headers only for (I believe) every piece of equipment on the list.... In other words, I get somewhere north of 37 emails, all blank.

Comment: Additional: hold the 37 emails. I've deleted over 400 already and they're still coming....

Comment: a ```}``` was missing, sorry I didn't test it out. I edited the first block of code

Comment: Playing with it, moved the "var" before "if". Now I get data in the logger but its ignoring the  `if (current+15 >= due) {` and showing me, I believe, everything on the sheet.

Comment: Reinstalled your update. Changed `      if (current+15 >= due) {
      Logger.log(equip + " " + current + " " +due)
        var equip = rowData[1]
        var current = rowData[18];'                 to                       `    var due = rowData[20];
    var equip = rowData[1]
    var current = rowData[18];
    if (due > 0) {
      if (current+15 >= due) {
      Logger.log(equip + " " + current + " " +due)`           which fixes the empty email but doesn't fix the repeating empty emails. Also, I couldn't save the project without adding `}' to the end of the code.

Comment: Probably a format problem, try to add ```parseInt(currrent)``` if you ok to work with integer, or add in your spreadsheet a number format

Comment: Hang on, moved a 3rd `}` before the `  var subject = "Services Due";
  MailApp.sendEmail({` . Now its giving me correctly filled emails, it just doesn't know when to stop. A 1 second execution code event returns over 30 (correct) emails. Adding a `;` below the message section seems to have stopped the diarrhea.

Comment: I edited my first block code with your full function, in order to have proper indentation

Comment: Its working great! Thanks! Now I just have to figure out the table layout options....